# Remove underlined span tag in wordpress title

Tags: html, css, wordpress, title, underline

I have placed a span tag around one word in the title section of one of my wordpress pages in the page editor. I have done this in order change the font family of this word in a child theme.

I was able to change the font family with this method but the word is now underlined and I am not able to remove it.

Does anyone know why this underline would appear? Maybe there is a better way for me to go about doing this?

Comment: you used text:decoration none and it did not work?

Comment: show us what you have done...show the css

Comment: let me go into a little more detail about what is going on. I'm using the free version of Accesspress Paralax theme. I placed this in the title of my page: Do you want your site to sounds like a <span>“scammy”</span> infomercial or ect.  Then I went into the child theme and made this code: #section-217 .mid-content .call-to-action h1 span{
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
 text-decoration:none !important;
 } This changed the font but for some reason there is an underline under the word. I'm not sure where that underline is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

As per the question , it's not really clear what you have used in css to remove the underline: but you can try with

```
span{
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

and also check if span is not inside an anchor tag  , if so try to give

```
a{
 text-decoration:none !important;
 }
```